# Unity3D Save or Load each Level and their own variables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save, load, binaryfiles

I am new to stackoverflow and  to Unity3D, so I am sorry if I am doing things wrong.

So currently, I am making a puzzle game. It has 50 different levels.
I need for each of them, to save 3 or 4 variables.
For example, when level 1 is cleared, I want it to store (int)hitCounts, (bool)cleared, (int)bestHitCounts.
I don't wanna use playerPrefs, as I don't want it to be readable from outside the box. I want it be converted to a binary file.
here is what I have :

#1 : made a static class TGameDat

```
[System.Serializable]
public class TGameDat 
{
    public int tGameDatInt;
    public bool tGameDatBool;
    public int tSceneIndex;

    public TGameDat (TPlayer player)
    {
        tGameDatInt = player.tInt;
        tGameDatBool = player.tBool;
        tSceneIndex = player.tScene;
    }
}
```

#2 : then made Tplayer(monobehaviour)

```
public class TPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int tInt = 0;
    public bool tBool = false;
    public int tScene;
    public List<TPlayer> TestGameDatList = new List<TPlayer>();

    private void Start()
    {
        TSceneMaker();
    }

    public void TSceneMaker()
    {
        tScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
    }

    public void TNextScene()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(tScene + 1);
    }

    public void TPreviousScene()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(tScene - 1);
    }

    public void TSaveVariables()
    {
        TSave.TSavePlayer(this);
        TestGameDatList.Add(this);
        Debug.Log("saved");
        Debug.Log(tInt + " " + tBool + " " + tScene);
    }

    public void TLoadVariables()
    {
        List<TGameDat> data = TSave.TLoadPlayer(this);
        Debug.Log("loaded. data count = " + data.Count + " tSceneIndex " + tScene);

                tInt = data[0].tGameDatInt;
                tBool = data[0].tGameDatBool;
                tScene = data[0].tSceneIndex;
    }
}
```

#3 : finally I created a save and load system :

```
public static class TSave
{
    public static void TSavePlayer (TPlayer player)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        List<TGameDat> data = new List<TGameDat>();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Tsave_" + player.tScene + ".fun";

        if(File.Exists(path))
        {
            FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
            data.Add(new TGameDat(player));
            formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
            stream.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            FileStream stream = File.Create(path);
            data.Add(new TGameDat(player));
            formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }

    public static List<TGameDat> TLoadPlayer(TPlayer player)
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Tsave_" + player.tScene + ".fun";
        if(File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
            List<TGameDat> data = new List<TGameDat>();
            
            data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as List<TGameDat>;
            stream.Close();
            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save file not found in " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

So, here are my problems :

1 : in the current situation, each scene compiles a binary file. So at the end, it will have a bunch of binary files piled up... Like 50, as I have 50 scenes... isn't it too many?

2 : of course I tried the make a single save file using List, and each level would come to add its own variable data in it.
But instead of adding the data, it would simply replace the previous data. Then there is always only 1 index in the List.
Therefore, when I load, the variables are from the last played level! And when I try to play another level after playing the first level, because there is only 1 index in the list, I get out of range error.

How shall I approach this?
sorry for the long long text!

thank you for your inputs!

Comment: A file in windows cannot be opened in both read and write mode.  So after reading existing file close.  Then add new player to your c# classes and open file again to save new serialized data.

Comment: You can use `PlayerPrefs` and encrypt the values for security.

Comment: @jdweng : Yes, I get it, that's why I open and close the file inTSave Class. And in each level, TPlayer is attached, and calls TSavePlayer or TLoadPlayer, and each time, I open and close, at least that what I tried to do, don't I? or is there something I don't see?

Comment: @Yaroslav : Really? how? you take the PlayerPrefs file and you encrypt like in binaries as I did here? can you point to me to a guide or a sample code please?

Comment: Look at method TSavePlayer (the IF/Else coode)

Comment: [EncryptedPlayerPrefs.cs](https://gist.github.com/ftvs/5299600)

Comment: @jdweng I don't get it. If file exists, I open the file, I write, and I close the stream. If the file does not exist, then I create the file, write, and close it. At least that is what I tried to do. what could be wrong?

Comment: @Yaroslav thank you for the link. I tried to understand it, but it still takes time to understand for me, so I will come back to you if I feel tooootally lost... thanks again!

Comment: Try flush() before close().  Check the file size to make sure the file is getting larger.  This will indate if the issue is with the reading or writing.  You should also open the file in write mode.

Answer (score 0):

first thing first, do you really need every level to have its own save data? Because if you only need to store the data between one level and another I would suggest you use some kind of PlayerState class that stores the data of the previous level.
But if you really need to store the data of every level then I'll recommend you using a [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0) rather than a simple list.

Here is an example of how I would do it
**Note: I haven't tested this code yet!**

SaveGameManager class

```
public string SavePath => Application.persistentDataPath + "/save.dat";

public static SaveGameManager Instance; // Singleton pattern
private Dictionary<string, TGameDat> gameData;

private void Awake()
{
    if (Instance != null)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        return;
    }

    // Singleton initialization
    Instance = this;
    // Keep the object when changing scenes
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    LoadGameData();
}

public TGameDat GetGameData(string key)
{
    if (gameData.TryGetValue(key, out TGameDat data))
    {
        return data;
    }

    Debug.Log($"Unable to find saved data with key {key}");
    return null;
}

public void SetGameData(string key, TGameDat data)
{
    // Sets a value with given key and save it to file
    gameData[key] = data;
    SaveGameData();
}

public void SaveGameData()
{
    Serializer.SaveBinaryFile(gameData, SavePath);
}

public void LoadGameData()
{
    var savedData = Serializer.LoadBinaryFile(SavePath);
    if (savedData != null)
    {
        gameData = (Dictionary<string, TGameDat>)savedData;
    }
    else
    {
        // Creating and saving new data because we can't found 
        // any that already stored in path
        gameData = new Dictionary<string, TGameDat>();
        SaveGameData();
    }
}
```

And then, the Serializer class

```
public static void SaveBinaryFile(object data, string path)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
    }
}

public static object LoadBinaryFile(string path)
{
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        // Trying to load a file that does not exist
        return null;
    }

    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this

```
public TGameDat data;

public void TSaveVariables()
{
    SaveGameManager.Instance.SetGameData(level.id, this.data);
}

public void TLoadVariables()
{
    var savedData = SaveGameManager.Instance.GetGameData(level.id);
    if (savedData != null)
    {
        this.data = savedData;
    }
    else
    {
        // We don't have any save file for this level yet
        savedData = new TGameDat();
    }
}
```

You can change `level.id` to whatever identifier you wanted to use.

Comment: woaaaaaaaah!!! <3 ok, I am going to test this! But first, I am going to check about Dictionary and understand the logic behind. But what you gave me gives me a really good idea. thank you so much! I will come back to you as soon as I tested it!

Comment: Great! Let me know if it's working for you, and if you have any questions, just let me know!

Comment: Oh, also, don't forget to call `DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);` on SaveGameManager's `Awake` function. I've edited the answer.

Comment: you are using Serializer and SaveBinaryFile. They are part of serizalization assets downloaded from the store, aren't they? just as info

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It was a simple script I wrote that only contains 2 static method

Comment: Ok thanks for the info! I am going to create my own as well then!